# How to make in Jax-rs @Path to accept an url encoded?

Tags: jax-rs

I'm trying to have this route working:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/settings/http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FApplication_software
```

where http://dbpedia.org/resource/Application_software is the ID for the item I want to get the settings. Instead, I've got this working:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/settings/http://dbpedia.org/resource/Application_software
```

Which is obviously not good if I want to pass other parameters after the url http://dbpedia.org/resource/Application_software.

The Get function code is:

```
@GET
@Path("/settings/{uri:^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]}")
public Response getUriSettings(
        @PathParam("uri") String uri, 
        @Context final HttpServletResponse response) {

    logger.debug("getting settings of " + uri);
...
```

I'm validating that I have a URL in the paramenter with regex, but I cannot pass this urlencoded...

How can I work around the problem to have that URL id encoded on the request?

Thanks!

Comment: Which JAX-RS implementation are you using?

Comment: You can't pass it as a query parameter?

Comment: @michal.gajdos I am using org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:2.3.1.GA.

Comment: @RickMangi I use this uri as an identifier of resuorces for making a restful implementation that uses only nouns. Thanks.